# Service Worker is not serving sub-pages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I've setup a service worker on my [blog](https://reidweb.com/), the home page correctly loads from the Service Worker cache, however visiting '[posts](https://reidweb.com/2017/02/06/cloudfront-cdn-tutorial/)' that I have previously visited while Chrome is set to be online they load, and in the developer tools they show as 'from ServiceWorker' as expected.

**However when I use the developer tools to set Chrome to offline, the pages are returning a status of 'failed'**

My question is why is this issue occurring?

My [serviceworker script](http://pastebin.com/Qd2KUEAn)

[ServiceWorker registration script](http://pastebin.com/hCz8HNMy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a regex in the path instead:

```
self.toolbox.router.get('/(.*)', function (request, values, options)
```

should do the trick without having 2 paths registered.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the URL structure of the site being

```
https://example.com/YYYY/MM/DD/post-title
```

I had to add a secondary block to handle the paths

```
self.toolbox.router.get('/**/*', function (request, values, options) {
```

This resolved the issue for me, as the existing block

```
self.toolbox.router.get('/*', function (request, values, options)
```

was not sufficient